# JQuery seems to be blocked by something else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, for-loop

### JQuery seems to be blocked

Hello there, I've been confronting this problem for several days, I just can't find a way to get this fixed, or around it.
What I want to do is simple, I want to read out every sub-folder of a big Project folder. Then assign a thumbnail image and a figcapture to this folder. With a simple for loop, php builds this for me. Everything works perfect and quick. The only thing is that the jquery won't respond. 
Even though I have created various menus with this technique. As you can see in my code, in the "script" tags, I have the jquery code which doesn't seem to work.
I don't know wheter php puts in a space somewhere or I just looked too long at this code for seing the error.


I appreciate any help.

```
<?php 


/*Because of the "ease of use" aspect of this site, I prefered to write it completely in PHP,
advantage of that: 
Images are loaded directly out of the folder, so I can just drag and drop something onto the server without having to write aditional code.
As you see, it can save a lot of time.*/


echo "<h1>Referenzen</h1><br>";

$projects = scandir('../src/sub/credentials');      //The credentials directory is being scanned and converted into an array.
    $projectsSize = count($projects);                       //$size is being created. It counts the number of objects in the array which has been created above.


$projectsCaptions = file('../src/sub/captionsOfCredentials.txt'); //Edit the name of the figcaption in the "captionsOfCredentials.txt".


for($i = 2; $i < $projectsSize; $i++){      /*Simple "for" loop, that creates $i with the size of two, because PHP is 0-index based and has the "dot" and the "dotdot" folder. The loop stops at the end of the array($size).*/
    echo    '<a href="index.php#PRJ'.trim($projectsCaptions[$i]).'" class="ID'.trim($projectsCaptions[$i]).'">
                <div class="projectFolder">
                    <img src="src/sub/credentialsThumb/project_00'.$i.'.jpg" width="100%" />
                        <figcaption>'
                            .$projectsCaptions[$i].
                        '</figcaption>
                </div>
            </a>'; 

        /*Project folder level starts here.*/
    $images = scandir('../src/sub/credentials/project_00'.$i);
        $imagesSize = count($images);

    for($k = 3; $k < $imagesSize; $k++){
        $tempID = ('ID'.trim($projectsCaptions[$i]).'.php');    //$tempID is the entire file name including the .php part.



            $handle = fopen($tempID, "a") or die ('Unable to open '.$tempID.' , please contact admin A.S.A.P..');
                $imagesCode = 'test';
                    fwrite($handle, $imagesCode);



    }
    //end second for-loop
                echo "
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ID".$projectsCaptions[$i]."').click(function () {
                $('#mainContent').load('de-DE/".$tempID."');
            });
        });
        </script>";
}
//end first for-loop

?>
```

Comment: I don't see where you actually create an element with that `id`. [edit] As the (suddenly deleted?) comment correctly pointed out, you are adding it as a class, instead of an id. So instead of `#ID...` you may want to use `.ID...`.

Comment: Can you open the page and view it's raw source? Show me how your `<script>` element is rendered!

Comment: your setter sets class  class="ID'.trim($projectsCaptions[$i])

Comment: @Arphrial im about to upload it, one second please

Comment: thank you @johnSmith even though it was an error, it wasn't the one that blocks the jquery. [denger](http://noahdenger.com/beta/denger) this is the site where you could look at the rendered code. go on architektur and then on unsere referenzen, this is where you can see what I am trying but failing...
don't worry, I will do the performance stuff in the end, it's just early beta

Comment: Updated my answer based on your site...

Comment: @MatW Thank you, you made my day. It works as I want it to work. I have been stuck with this for ages....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting an element by **id** when you need to use **class**. Change the JS block to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Note ".ID" not "#ID"  
    $('.ID".$projectsCaptions[$i]."').click(function () {
        $('#mainContent').load('de-DE/".$tempID."');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

It seems like you've also got an illegal character in `$projectsCaptions[$i]`. It's most likely a newline character. Try wrapping the above reference above in `trim()`:

```
$('.ID" . trim($projectsCaptions[$i]) . "').click(function () {
```

Comment: This looks to be correct. Your links are generated using `class` attributes as their identifiers:
`class="ID'.trim($projectsCaptions[$i]).'"`. The jQuery is not working because it's trying to bind an event to an element which doesn't exist.

Comment: However it still does not work... I'll upload it on the server, so you can have a look at it. just a minute please

Comment: [denger test](http://noahdenger.com/beta/denger/)
go on architektur and then on referenzen,
this is where the magic happens
@Arphrial